# Taylor expansion of $1/(1+z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

How do I obtain the Taylor expansion of $$\frac{1}{1+z}$$ about $a=i$ please? 
Do I just expand the series using the binomial expansion?

Answer (score 4):

**Here is a start**:

> $$ \frac{1}{1+z} = \frac{1}{(1+i)+(z-i)}= \frac{1}{1+i} \frac{1}{1+\frac{(z-i)}{1+i}} = \dots\,.$$

You need to use the geometric series to expand the last expression.

**Note:**

> $$ \frac{1}{1+t} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k t^k, \quad |t|<1.$$

Comment: @Timbuc: You are right! But as you see I gave him these things in the note. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: how did you obtain the third expression please?

Comment: I just factored out $1+i$.